# HTML Anchors Not Working

Tags: html

I'm trying to assign different anchors to different divs, but they don't seem to be taking effect. I've tried using `<a name="anchor">`, `<a id="anchor">`, and `<div id="anchor">` (which worked with some divs, but not all).

This is my current HTML:

```html
<div class="about">
  <a name="nabout"></a>
  <div class="section">

    <div class="section-title job-section-header section-header section-subheader">
      <div class="section-bar"></div>
      <img src="images/about-photo.png" class="left-image" />
    </div>
    <div class="section-body jobs">
      <p class="section-subtext-md section-subtext section-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis lobortis nulla a eros porttitor, ut congue elit commodo. Nunc ut dapibus elit. Suspendisse euismod rhoncus felis, id vulputate mauris posuere vitae. Praesent bibendum maximus nibh, nec
        tempor diam blandit in. Praesent non metus in odio vehicula cursus vulputate quis quam. Nulla varius massa ac libero commodo imperdiet. Fusce tincidunt metus sapien, sed fringilla nibh vulputate eget. Suspendisse sodales nisi quis hendrerit porttitor.
        Morbi in augue sapien. Maecenas ultricies, nisl vitae vehicula vulputate, nunc tellus sagittis turpis, nec laoreet quam velit non nunc. In aliquam libero a tellus commodo, at aliquet risus imperdiet. Fusce finibus a nulla et facilisis. Maecenas
        condimentum sit amet velit et sodales. Duis mauris augue, feugiat non ornare pharetra, convallis nec metus. Integer vitae consequat dolor, at tristique lorem.</p>

      <p class="section-subtext-md section-subtext section-text">Cras libero massa, fringilla id condimentum ut, aliquam ut nisi. Vestibulum ullamcorper commodo elit at commodo. Nullam dignissim id lacus sed faucibus. Quisque sollicitudin quam sit amet est facilisis tempor. Morbi vehicula quam et mauris faucibus
        semper. Etiam vel est eu magna viverra viverra. Donec venenatis, nisl eget rhoncus auctor, lorem est gravida magna, ac consectetur velit libero at turpis. Vivamus at quam sed arcu eleifend suscipit non id mauris. Pellentesque tempor ornare imperdiet.
        Morbi ornare luctus imperdiet. Fusce sagittis lorem ut elementum fermentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does `<a name>` not work sometimes and what should I be using in this case?

Comment: Where's your link href?

Comment: Your link has no content. What's it supposed to do?

Comment: @Warface `<a href="home.html#nabout">About</a>`

Comment: @j08691 It's just there to serve as the jump spot for the anchor. I tried wrapping it around `<div class="section">`, but it didn't make a difference

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Hyperlink

Comment: I think you have a closed </a> misplaced. `<a name="#services"><div class="services"></a>` https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.mtscollective.com%2Fhome.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0):

The way that HTML anchors works is as follows.

When you give a `div` or any other DOM object an `id`  attribute, you can then "link" to that object by specifying that id, with a `#` in your `href`, to have an a tag link to that tag.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#testing">Testing</a>

...

<div id="testing">
    <h1>Testing DIV</h1>
</div>
```

By clicking on the above `<a>` tag, the user's browser will scroll until the very top of the `#testing` div is at the top of the page, assuming the browser has space to scroll.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I mentioned that I tried this method, though it only worked on some divs/anchors and not with the "About" div

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean when you say it does not work with the about div? It's possible it cannot scroll, or you duplicated an ID, or used illegal characters in the id?

Comment: I mean that when I added the div ID of "nabout" and linked to it in an href, it didn't scroll down to that section of the page

Comment: Can you provide that code or recreate it in a fiddle?

Comment: Hmm it seems like it works on JSFiddle if I extract the div in question (http://jsfiddle.net/cnkwneto/), and even when it's in context of the full page (http://jsfiddle.net/srr2penq/). I'm really unsure why it doesn't work in my project

Comment: Can you provide more code? It's something in the page that's disabling it, or it doesn't have enough room to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="#test">Test</a>

.........

<a name="test"></a>
<h1>Testing</h1>
```

or this

```
<a href="#test">Test</a>

    .......

    <div id="test">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure why it's not jumping to the location on load, but if you add this javascript

```
window.location.href = window.location.hash;
```

to the bottom of the page, that should fix your problem.